# Error setting image src by id in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to link an image so that when I check or uncheck a box it will appear and disappear. I have nav buttons that dictate which images shall appear. The HTML code is as follows.

```js
function p01Func() {
  document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML = "<p>I'm looking for a type of pancake originating from the Indian subcontinent, made from a fermented batter. It is somewhat similar to a crepe in appearance.</p>";

  document.getElementById("flowchart").setAttribute("src", "images/dosa/dosaDesign.jpg");

  document.getElementById("js").setAttribute("src," "images/dosa/dosa1.jpg");

  document.getElementbyId("another").setAttribute("src," "images/dosa/dosa2.jpg");

  document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("check3").checked = false;
}

p01Func();
```

```html
<div class="column1 design">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" /> Design
  <img id="flowchart" src="null" alt="null" />
</div>
<div class="column2 jsSolution">
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" /> JavaScript Solution
  <img id="js" src="null" alt="null" />
</div>
<div class="column3 otherSolution">
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox" /> Another Solution
  <img id="another" src="null" alt="null" />
</div>
```

The code won't run anymore, even the other parts. Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of doing it this way. Why don't you just have the image always there but hide it? Surely that would be easier

Comment: It's for a course and I was told to do it this way, I know it's a questionable way to go about it. The instructions tell me to write that code and then set the display to none so that I can later write check functions to display the image.

Comment: What do you mean 'the code won't run anymore'? What code? The entire solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in 2 of your `setAttribute()` methods.

The following incorrect syntax (comma inside the double quotes after `src`):

```
document.getElementById("js").setAttribute("src," "images/dosa/dosa1.jpg");
```

Should be replaced with:

```
document.getElementById("js").setAttribute("src", "images/dosa/dosa1.jpg");
```

You also made the same syntax error in the line that follows this one. You can check your browser console to find these sorts of errors.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I'm an idiot. Really appreciate it.